# Rails pg array, can't save items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added an array column with

`add_column :mailboxes, :allowed_fields, :string, array: true, default: []`

then `allowed_fields: []` at the end of my strong params

But when I submit a form with `allowed_fields` set to

`123, 123` I got the following in my terminal logs 
`"allowed_fields"=>"123, 123"`

and

`[123, 123]` - `"allowed_fields"=>"[123,123]"`

but the record value is not updated/saved

If I try to add an item to `allowed_fields` field from console, it works

```
object.allowed_fields << "lalal"
object.save
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: This may not be the solution, but use `text` as the data type in PostgreSQL, not `string`.

Comment: I'd tried text before posting my question. Didn't work

Comment: Can you post view and controller code, and the complete strong param statement?

Comment: Check the `#validation` and `#before_save` what's the error?

Comment: I've just figured out that `:allowed_fields` insted of `allowed_fields: []` in strong params saves the field but the first value inside of it is missing

Comment: try `:allowed_fields => []` as last argument of params, see if it works

Comment: @srs did you read my question? `allowed_fields: []` is the same what you're offering. Anyway I decided to give up the idea with arrays and use a simple string with split.

Comment: And did you also keep `allowed_fields: []` as "LAST ARGUMENT" of strong params

Comment: @srs are you kidding? `at the end of my strong params`  3rd line of the question

Comment: because it is a common error, anyways `:allowed_fields` is working for you?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Using **PostgresSql**

Try datatype :text, more on - [character types](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-arrays-in-rails-with-postgresql/)

```
class Mailbox < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :mailboxes, :allowed_fields, :text, array:true, default: []
  end
end
```

Old

**Preferred way**

Have you considered serialize `Mailbox.rb` for array inputs. I will start from here.

```
class Mailbox < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :allowed_fields, Array
end

mailbox = Mailbox.new
mailbox.allowed_fields = ["123", "123"]
mailbox.save
```

Remember, you have define `allowed_fields` as `t.string` type in your `Mailbox.rb` schema? `["123", "123"]` should be input rather `[123, 123]`. Else whole input will be considered as one element and saved.

Some read more 1. [One](http://thelazylog.com/using-serialize-option-in-ruby-on-rails/)
               2. [Two](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)

Comment: Defining the data type in the database as an Array should be enough. No need to use `serialize`

Comment: :array is Postgres database data type. serialize is the preferred way

Comment: Recent versions of the PostgreSQL adapter do not need `serialize` -- if the data type is an `Array` is just works.

Comment: `serialize` does not need a `PostgreSQL` adapter, it is just a generic solution for `Array`, `Hash` and etc, works well on `ActiveRecord`, as @kirqe has not mentioned his adapter.

Comment: Well, I would rather you took "Preferred way" out of your answer, or at least qualified it with the circumstances under which it is preferred. On recent versions of Rails, using PostgreSQL, it would in no way be preferred for `Array`, `Json`, `Jsonb`, or various other types. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Comment: i tried it with text. It works fine with string too. As I told the problem is that it only works from console.

Comment: Any `#validation`/`#before_save` in your model? suggest trying `:serialize` once. @David FYI: assumptions to use `pgadapter` shows a little overkill, definitely definitely not a discourage to `PostgreSql`. Keeping it basic activerecord compatible adds flexibility and keeps it preferred as contrary the other way around